# Convert JSON to POJO with different data type

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, pojo

I have this response, i have problem when  i want to convert to pojo.

```
"equity": {
            "0": {
                "name": [
                    "Abc"
                ],
                "code": [
                    "3410"
                ],
                "ending_balance": [
                    301834470
                ]
            },
            "1": {
                "name": [
                    "Xyz"
                ],
                "code": [
                    "2180"
                ],
                "ending_balance": [
                    0
                ]
            },
            "2": {
                "name": [
                    "Pqr"
                ],
                "code": [
                    "9220"
                ],
                "ending_balance": [
                    0
                ]
            },
            "total_equity": 301834470
        }
    }
```

I'm confused about giving the right data type, because there are arrays("0","1","2") that contain objects and "total_equity" that contain number.
I've tried to give the map data type, but it will be error for "total_equity"

```
var equity: Map<String, EquityDto?>
```

If you know the solution for this problem please help me. Thank you

Comment: Your Json is wrong. The level one (equity) is open as object but it should be an array. Also you level 2.

Comment: Why don't you use `array` instead of objects for repeating `keys` ?

Comment: I didn't make the api, I just consume it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var equity: Map<String, Any>
```

While accessing the Any Data type u can compare the varrriable type(instance of) and use the value as following

```
if (valueofMap is Int){
//here is integer value
}

if (valueofMap is yourDataClass){
//your custom class
}
```

Comment: it causes an error when i want to cast the Any to my data class

Comment: i using 'as' to cast Any to my class

Comment: welcome. please give me an accept & upvote

Comment: when I compare my valueOfMap with myDataClass it always return false.

Comment: when i log the valueOfMap it return 
{classification=Abcd, name=[xyz], code=[1234], ending_balance=[1000.0], total=1000.0} 

and my data class is 
data class Item (
    var classification: String? = null,
    var name: List<String>? = null,
    var code: List<String>? = null,
    var ending_balance: List<Double>? = null,
    var total: Double? = 0.0
) 
is my data class wrong?

Comment: can you provide the method by what your traversing your map and compare?

Comment: I use 
myMap.map{
if (it.value is Item) ...
else ...
}

Answer (score 0):

There can be a solution to this, but it will be a lengthy one.

One solution can be to transform the response to `Map<String, Any>` then you will have to check the type every time you have to use it and it can really annoying when you are using it in multiple classes.

Another solution can be to create a custom `Custom Type Adapter` which you can pass to the `Retrofit` Instance in the `addConverterFactory` method.

To create a custom adapter, you just have to follow the following steps:

1. Create a model in which you want to store the data. In your case it can be :

```
data class ApiResponse(
     val data: Map<String, EquityDto?>,
     val totalEquity:Int
)
```

2. Create the Adapter:

```
class StudentAdapter : TypeAdapter<ApiResponse?>() {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun read(reader: JsonReader): ApiResponse {
        val student:ApiResponse? = null
        reader.beginObject()
        var fieldname: String? = null
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            var token = reader.peek()
            if (token == JsonToken.NAME) {
                //get the current token
                fieldname = reader.nextName()
            }

            if ("total_equity" == fieldname) {
                token = reader.peek()
                student?.totalEquity = reader.nextInt()
            }else {
                token = reader.peek()
                student?.data?.set(fieldname.toString(), reader.nextString())
            }
        }
        reader.endObject()
        return student
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun write(writer: JsonWriter, student: ApiResponse) {
        writer.beginObject()
        writer.name("data")
        writer.value(student.data.toString())
        writer.name("totalEquity")
        writer.value(student.totalEquity)
        writer.endObject()
    }
}
```

If you know a better way to create a type adapter then you can surely use that.